# Displaying submitted data from database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

What I want to do is when the user clicks submit, the data gets entered to the database and it will redirect me to like a Thank you page showing what the user has submitted.

code snippet: html code & php code:

```
   <form action="ThankYouReport.html" method="post"           
         enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <div> 
        <div class="container">

            <label><input 
              type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Beans">Beans</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Apple" >  
        Apple</label>
   </div>
   </form>
  <?php  
  require('config.php');
  if(isset($_POST['sub']))  
  {    
      $checkbox1=$_POST['check'];  
      $chk="";  
      foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
         {  
            $chk .= $chk1.",";  
         }

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `list` (`checked1`) VALUES ( ','$chk')") or           
            die(mysql_error());

      }  
  ?>
```

I looked around and saw that you had to change the form action, I did that but for some reason my data won't get entered in my database.

How would I go about displaying the data to another page.

I know there been many post on this site but none of them help me.

Comment: Move the $_POST above the html, and then use header() to send to the new page  Header only works if it is executed before any other html

Comment: what do you mean by moving the $_POST above the html, which _POST are you talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see the comments within:

```
<?php
session_start(); // always do this at the very top of your script
require('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {

    $chk = implode(',',$_POST['check']); // shorter than using foreach

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `list` (`checked1`) VALUES ('{$chk}')"; // just a way of storing a query to a variable

    if(mysql_query($sql)) {

        $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'Successfully added items '.$chk; // store a message or whatever into a session variable
        // FYI if you wrap a string with single quotes, you cannot use a variable within like in above query string, but have to be concatenated using a dot (.)
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/ThankYouReport.html'); // redirect on success
    } else {
        die('Could not insert query'); // or print this message
    }

}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><!-- remove action attribute or use name of script this is in. -->
    <div class="container">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Beans"> Beans</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Apple"> Apple</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

EDIT (based on the comment)

If you want to transfer data from one script to another, especially for something simple as a thank you page or similar you can use php sessions. You need to turn your thank you page into a PHP script like so:

thanks.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
<div>
<?php echo $_SESSION['success_msg'];?>
</div>
```

Comment: does the php code need to be on top of the html code?

Comment: Yes. `header('Location: http://www.example.com/ThankYouReport.html');` only works when NO output is done before. If even a space is shown you will get an error.

Comment: thanks it worked, but how do I get it display what I have submitted on the ThankYouReport.html

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work, would I need to change the 'sucesss_msg' to something else?

Comment: That must be related to a key that you named 'some_key'. You must be saying something like this `echo $someVariable['some_key'];` when you never set that key. Wrap that into an isset() function where ever it occurs. So  `if(isset($someVariable['some_key'])) { echo $someVariable['some_key']; }`. I have tested above snippet and is works. Just that i had to check if the key 'check' not 'sub' existed in $_POST.

Comment: didn't realize you changed your original answered and added the session in that code too. Thanks it works perfectly.